# How to pass ArgumentMatcher correctly using Mockito

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mocking, mockito

Hi in my unit test I am getting an error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.xx.xxx.clean.orderview.domain.OnStandUseCaseCoroutine$Params.<init>, parameter action`

The error is at the parameter `action` which is in my usecase whose type is `TimeStampedAction` which is a `class`

I had similar issue for paremeter serviceType and id and when I changed from any() to anyString() it worked fine but I am not sure how to do the same for `capture(actionCaptor)`

```
class OnStandUseCaseCoroutine @Inject constructor(
    private val orderRepository: OrderRepository,
    private val serviceOrderTypeProvider: ServiceOrderTypeProvider
) : UseCaseCoroutine<GenericResponse, OnStandUseCaseCoroutine.Params> (){

    override suspend fun run(params: Params) =
        orderRepository.notifyOnStandSuspend(serviceOrderTypeProvider.apiPathFor(params.serviceType), params.id, params.action)

    data class Params(val serviceType: String, val id: String, val action: TimestampedAction)
}

@Test
    fun `test case`() {
        val actionCaptor = argumentCaptor<TimestampedAction>()
        val timestamp = DateTime.now()

        every(noServiceRequiredBus.get()).thenReturn(Observable.just(REQUESTED))
        every(timingsUpdater.timestampCalculator(any(), any())).thenReturn(timestamp)

        baseOrderViewPresenter.setView(view)
        baseOrderViewPresenter.notifyOnStand()

        runBlocking {
            verify(onStandUseCaseCoroutine).run(OnStandUseCaseCoroutine.Params(anyString(), anyString(), capture(actionCaptor)))
        }

    }
```

Edit

Presenter layer functions

```
override fun notifyOnStand() {
    notifyOnStandApi(this::onStandResponseSuccess)
}

override fun notifyOnStandApi(callback: (GenericResponse?) -> Unit) {
    val serviceOrder = orderStorage.serviceOrder!!

    view?.showLoader()

    val timestamp = timingsUpdater.timestampCalculator(serviceOrder, getEquipment())

    val action = TimestampedAction(
        app.session.user.id, null, timestamp
    )

    try {
        onStandUseCaseCoroutine(OnStandUseCaseCoroutine.Params(serviceOrder.serviceType, serviceOrder.id, action)) {
            callback.invoke(it)
        }
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        onStandResponseErrors()
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance
R

Comment: Have you stubbed notifyOnStandSuspend?

Comment: I am not stubbing, should I be doing that? I have updated by question with my presenter where I am using the usecase

Comment: Please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174590/mockito-argumentcaptor-is-returning-null

Comment: @LajosArpad I had a look, I am pretty new to this, could you please elaborate on what to do to fix it please

Comment: I probably know less about this than you, this is why I'm only commenting based on what I found online, instead of answering.

Comment: no problem @LajosArpad thank you though, will have a look,